# Combination of querySelectorAll and appendChild is not working

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, appendchild, selectors-api

I have multiple definition lists with lots of `dt` elements spread across them. I would like to append `button` inside each `dt`, but I have no idea why my code isn’t working.

Here is what I tried:

```
const button = Object.assign(document.createElement("button"), {
  type: "button"
})

const descriptionTerms = document.querySelectorAll("dt")
// Or should I use:
// const descriptionTerms = [...document.getElementsByTagName("dt")]?

descriptionTerms.forEach(descriptionTerm => {
  descriptionTerm.appendChild(button)
})
```

What am I doing wrong? What’s the most elegant way to do this using `ECMAScript 6`?

Comment: what's your descriptionTerms.length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you are trying to append the same button object to multiple parents, which is wrong. To fix the issue, create a button for every `dt`:

```js
descriptionTerms.forEach(descriptionTerm => {
  const button = Object.assign(document.createElement("button"), {
    type: "button"
  })
  descriptionTerm.appendChild(button)
})
```

See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) for more info:

> The Node.appendChild() method adds a node to the end of the list of children of a specified parent node. **If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document**, appendChild() moves it from its current position to the new position (there is no requirement to remove the node from its parent node before appending it to some other node).

Another way is to clone the existing button:

> This means that a node can't be in two points of the document simultaneously. So if the node already has a parent, the node is first removed, then appended at the new position. The Node.cloneNode() method can be used to make a copy of the node before appending it under the new parent. Note that the copies made with cloneNode will not be automatically kept in sync.